# Switch monitors off with a shell command

Tags: x11, monitors

I want to use a command line tool to switch two monitors (HDMI and DP) off (standby).
They are supposed to switch on again on after any input (keyboard, mouse) like the idle standby only done on command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
sleep 1; xset dpms force off s activate
```

The `sleep` is there to give you time to release the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. :)